# Comparison theory for second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, dynamical-systems, functional-inequalities

Let's say we have a second-order differential equation of the form:
$$
y''(t)= a(t)y'(t)+b(t)y(t).
$$
Assume also that $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are bounded, positive for all time, and with any regularity we wish.

**QUESTION:**
If I have now an inequality of the form
$$
f''(t)\leq a(t)f'(t)+b(t)f(t),
$$
is there any relation between $y(t)$ and $f(t)$? Something like Gronwall's inequality or Petrovitsch theorem for a second-order ODE?